# Associate custom client certificate to Azure Self-hosted Gateway

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I am working with Azure API management.
I have deployed a self-hosted gateway on my local machine, and I want to associate custom client certificates for security.
I have successfully uploaded a custom certificate to Azure API Management in the Portal and associated it with the API.

Now I need to associate this certificate with the self-hosted gateway. I cannot find any clear material on the internet.
How I can do this step?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in Microsoft's document [Add a custom CA certificate - Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ca-certificates#create-custom-ca-for-self-hosted-gateway):

> ### Create custom CA for self-hosted gateway
>
> If you use a [self-hosted gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview),
> validation of server and client certificates using CA root
> certificates uploaded to API Management service is not supported. To
> establish trust, configure a specific client certificate so that it's
> trusted by the gateway as a custom certificate authority.
>
> Use the [Gateway Certificate Authority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/gateway-certificate-authority)
> REST APIs to create and manage custom CAs for a self-hosted gateway.
> To create a custom CA:
>
> 1. [Add a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates)
>    .pfx file to your API Management instance.
> 2. Use the [Gateway Certificate Authority - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/gateway-certificate-authority/create-or-update) REST API to associate the certificate with the self-managed gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually I already followed the instructions in this tutorial and I am struggling with the second step: Use the Gateway Certificate Authority REST API to associate the certificate with the self-managed gateway.
It is not clear how to perform this step

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? It's pretty clear by following the link provided that you need to make a POST request against the specified URL, passing all the necessary parameters you need to associate the certificate. Which part *specifically* are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: When I make the request, I get an error Response Code 400 as below

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Representation was empty.",
    "details": null
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

For error Response Code 400 { "error": { "code": "ValidationError", "message": "Representation was empty.", "details": null } }

you have to set your request body to :

"properties": {
"isTrusted": true
}